# INSERT Trigger in MSSQL: destination table by Variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

Several Programs/Processes insert their history in one single (very big) history table (tbl_History). I cannot change that. I have to sort them into the "right" history tables on insert. These different History tables do already exist. I will not create then. But by the parameter "his_ID" I can examine, witch table is the right destination table.

So I added a trigger into this table. This one works:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Trigger_tbl_History_Insert]
ON [dbo].[tbl_History]
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO [tbl_Historyef33894e-3fda-4833-b1e6-efa5cb9ce8ee] SELECT * FROM inserted;
END
```

but now I would like to decide the destination Table by a variable within the new inserted line. I thought something like that:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Trigger_tbl_History_Insert]
ON [dbo].[tbl_History]
AFTER INSERT
AS

BEGIN
    DECLARE @hisID varchar(max);
    SELECT @hisID = inserted.his_ID FROM inserted;
    INSERT INTO [tbl_History + @hisID ] SELECT * FROM inserted;
END
```

apparently it does not work this way. :-) Is there a way to achieve that?

**Following approaches did not work completely correctly:**

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Trigger_tbl_History_Insert]
ON [dbo].[tbl_History]
AFTER INSERT
AS

BEGIN
    DECLARE @hisID varchar(max);
    SELECT @hisID = inserted.his_ID FROM inserted;
    EXEC ('INSERT INTO tbl_History' + @hisID + '  SELECT * FROM inserted');
END
```

*Creates the Error: "Incorrect syntax near '-'"*

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Trigger_tbl_History_Insert]
ON [dbo].[tbl_History]
AFTER INSERT
AS

BEGIN
    DECLARE @hisID varchar(max);
    SELECT @hisID = inserted.his_ID FROM inserted;
    EXEC ('INSERT INTO [tbl_History' + @hisID + ']  SELECT * FROM inserted');
END
```

*Creates the error: "Invalid object name 'inserted'."*

Comment: You mean after every insert you want to save data into **[tbl_History + @hisID ]** right ??. If your answer is yes then it means at every insert it'll create new table as per the id and save the data!!!

Comment: I am not sure if you can use, but put `Insert` into dynamic code....

Comment: First yes, than no. ;-) It does not create a new Table. The table does already exists. Several Programs/Processes insert they history in one single history table. I cannot change that. I have to sort them into the "right" history tables on insert. I will add this explanation right now to the post.

Comment: @Tagamoga: You mean to say that [tbl_History123] is already created or exists. you just need to insert data into them via trigger right ???. Here 123 is your **@hisID**.

Comment: Yes that is right. **@hisID** is filled by the inserted.his_ID

Comment: You are more likely to need to declare as much variables as you have fields in your table, then run an `EXEC` command with the appropriate insert statement.

Comment: How can you receive two different errors with the same code? See you edit using the `EXEC` command.

Comment: It is not the same code... please notice the brackets.

Comment: How many different tables are you dealing with? For a robust trigger, you ought to write one that can deal with *multiple* rows in `inserted` and those rows may have different values for `his_id`. So the cleanest trigger would just attempt to insert into every history table with an appropriate `WHERE` clause to filter `inserted` down to just the rows that should hit that table. But that can get fiddly if the number of destination tables is large.

Comment: unfortunately I am not quite free to tell them, that the number of History table is too big. :-( But the for Each loop will bee surly added. For testing and explaining the assumption of one row was enough... ;-) Thank you for the hint!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, Here i assume that table named **[tbl_History123]** would exists where 123 is variable @hisID. So in that case you can do this something like this -

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Trigger_tbl_History_Insert]
ON [dbo].[tbl_History]
AFTER INSERT
AS

BEGIN
    DECLARE @hisID varchar(max);
    SELECT @hisID = inserted.his_ID FROM inserted;

    EXEC ('INSERT INTO tbl_History' + @hisID + '  SELECT * FROM inserted');

    -- OR you can also do this
    EXEC (
        'SELECT * 
         INTO tbl_History' + @hisID + '
         FROM inserted'
        );

END
```

### EDITED

Okay, make another separate table let say - **tmpHistoryForID** with same schema as your [tbl_History123] have. This works as mediator table. So in trigger first insert data into this table and then from this table to insert into your [tbl_History123] table. Like this  -

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Trigger_tbl_History_Insert]
    ON [dbo].[tbl_History]
    AFTER INSERT
    AS

BEGIN
        DECLARE @hisID varchar(max);
        SELECT @hisID = inserted.his_ID FROM inserted;

        INSERT INTO dbo.tmpHistoryForID 
            SELECT * FROM inserted

        EXEC ('INSERT INTO tbl_History' + @hisID + '  SELECT * FROM dbo.tmpHistoryForID');

        TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.tmpHistoryForID

END
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, but still that is not running. Unfortunate following error occurs: "Incorrect syntax near '-'." When I change the EXEC-line to 'EXEC ('INSERT INTO [tbl_History' + @hisID + ']  SELECT * FROM inserted');' it tells me: "Invalid object name 'inserted'." I Will add that to the post too...

Comment: The `EXEC` or `EXECUTE` statement is used when you want to achieve something that SQL Server won't allow on the first parse. Actually, SQL Server parses your instructions and check for any errors. Because your table `tblHistory + @hisID` doesn't exist, namely `[tblHistory + @hidID]`, it won't allow you. So, using the `EXEC` or `EXECUTE` command differs the parse to "runtime".

Comment: The tables DO Exists. Otherwise "INSERT INTO [tbl_Historyef33894e-3fda-4833-b1e6-efa5cb9ce8ee] SELECT * FROM inserted;" would not have been working.

Comment: @Tagamoga: I have updated my answer. See edited section

Comment: I love you! But please add "[]" to your statement, because MSSQL dont like "-" in table names *bg* : "EXEC ('INSERT INTO [tbl_History' + @userID + ']  SELECT * FROM dbo.tbl_tmpHistoryForID');"

Answer (score 0):

You can't access magic tables with dynamic SQL queries. Before executing dynamic query put the records into a temp table. Below is the code for trigger.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Trigger_tbl_History_Insert]
ON [dbo].[tbl_History]
AFTER INSERT
AS

BEGIN
    DECLARE @ID int;
    DECLARE @Qry varchar(max)
    SELECT @ID = inserted.ID FROM inserted;
    select * into #tmp from inserted
    SET @Qry=CONCAT('INSERT INTO tbl_History' , @ID ,'  SELECT * FROM #tmp')
    EXEC (@Qry)
END
```